# How to use the Action Scheduler WordPress job queue

Tags: wordpress

I need to implement batch processing in a WordPress plugin that I am building because one of the functions requires a lot of processing time (API queries, images downloads, inserting posts, etc).

The [Action Scheduler](https://github.com/Prospress/action-scheduler) library looks like a good solution, but I'm confused about how to implement it.

I have the plugin installed, and the Readme doc says I can then use various functions such as `as_schedule_single_action( $timestamp, $hook, $args, $group )` to process tasks.

How do I use a function like that to queue up batches of tasks?

For example, how would I queue up each these tasks to run in the background using Action Scheduler:

```
$lower_case_names = array('mary', 'bob', 'trent', 'bill', 'jane');

function make_names_uppercase ($lower_case_names) {
    $upper_case_names = array();
    foreach ($lower_case_names as $name) {
        $upper_case_names[] = strtoupper($name);
    }
    return $upper_case_names;
}
```

Comment: See this issue, where the question is referenced https://github.com/Prospress/action-scheduler/issues/204

Answer (score 7):

To run `make_names_uppercase()` via Action Scheduler, you need to first add an action/hook to the queue, then attach your `make_names_uppercase()` function as a callback to that scheduled action.

That means code something like this:

```
$names = array( 'mary', 'bob', 'trent', 'bill', 'jane' );

// Schedule an action name 'make_names_uppercase_action' with specific first name data
as_schedule_single_action( time(), 'make_names_uppercase_action', array( 'names' => $names ) );

add_action( 'make_names_uppercase_action', 'make_names_uppercase', 10, 1 );
```

The `make_names_uppercase()` function will then receive one parameter, the `$names` array when Action Scheduler triggers the `'make_names_uppercase_action'` hook.

I figured I'd answer here as well as [GitHub](https://github.com/Prospress/action-scheduler/issues/204#issuecomment-430594504) as Stackoverflow is better indexed than GitHUb.

I've also published a usage guide to help with these kinds of questions on the new [Action Scheduler site](https://actionscheduler.org/usage/#scheduling-an-action).